# Do UL-listed product specifications or NEC rules take precedence?

Tags: code-compliance

An interesting question arose elsewhere.  Suppose you break out a "New, Old Stock" item.  It is UL-approved and has UL-approved instructions.

The instructions say to do X.

However, since the item was UL-approved, NEC has changed.  Doing X is now explicitly forbidden, and you must do Y.

Which one controls?  Are you obliged to follow the instructions?

Are you obliged to follow current NEC?

Are you obliged to throw the item in the trash and get a modern one whose UL-approved instructions are consistent with NEC?

Comment: Sounds like the solution may be **ask your AHJ**. But perhaps this question is itself an XY question: Give us an example (60A heater circuit?) as opposed to generic "UL vs. NEC".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I don't think it's an XY question; it's asking if there's a rule or general principle as far as which one takes precedence.  If there is no such principle, and every AHJ makes these kind of decisions on a case-by-case basis, then that's an answer.

Comment: maybe it would help everyone provide a better answer if you provide information on what is "now explicitly forbidden".

Comment: @programmer66 I think you would find a hard time finding a forbidden MFG over ride because the word shall in 110.3.B , shall means it is mandatory most apprenticeships at least in my state teach this in the first year.

Comment: Yes- That is the point I am making, What is this forbidden instruction.  The reality is NOT to do anything that is unsafe or dangerous  even if a code or manufacture's states to do it.  But the forbidden instruction is in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple... 110.3.B states that the manufacturer's instructions shall be followed. That is, of course, for listed equipment.

Comment: Even for really old stuff? Are there any time stipulations?

Comment: I don't think it's always the case that manufacturer instructions override the NEC, or at least not all AHJs interpret it that way.  One really common example is older refrigerators that say do not plug into a GFCI in their labeling (because it'll trip), while modern code requires GFCIs everywhere you might put a fridge.  My understanding is that the only way to make that work is with an AHJ variance, and not every AHJ will give one.

Comment: My two cents - The manufacture did the testing and met the UL requirement for obtaining the UL listing.  NEC writes code to states how things should be in a perfect world.  The NEC write these codes based on statistics and what is general best practice for doing something, and feedback from manufactures and organizations.  They do no testing.  That is the reason why a manufacture instructions takes precedence.  I see comment about AHJ, which is NOT the NEC

Comment: I don't believe NEC code requires a fridge to be on a GFCI,  Specific outlet locations in specific areas need to be GFCI protected.  Most recommendations I have seen, if possible, the fridge should not be on a GFCI circuit.

Comment: NEC does not require GFCI specifically for fridges -- kitchen fridges in dwelling units don't require it since only the countertop receptacles in dwelling unit kitchens require GFCI protection, not receptacles for other things (save for the dishwasher)

Comment: @nate s you are wrong the inspector has to cite a violation in the case a refrigerator states a non GFCI with a current listing see the code SHALL is mandatory if something is 50 years old it may not have a current listing but if matches the code when built some states actually allow it and some historic zones require it.

Answer (score 2):

We all know the manufacturer's instructions have to be followed. If the items are being reintroduced into the market they's have to be re certified and instructions updated.
So I find an new, unopened 48" fluorescent bathroom fixture in my attic that the builder left 55 years ago. It has a two prong outlet built into it. It was UL- approved. I want to install it in  my new house being built. The instructions say to hook it up to a hot and neutral and wall mount it. The instructions don't mention anything about a ground or GFCI protection for the outlet. The current code requires both now and I doubt you'd find an inspector who would say the instructions override the current codes.

Comment: I agree. You must follow the manufacturer's *current* instructions for the product, which may have changed since the packaging was printed.

Comment: The manufacturer's instruction does not state NOT to use a ground.  Based on the NEC code, you would have the three wires, and connect the ground wire to the fixture frame.   You are still following the manufacturer's instruction and supplementing it was additional requirements from the NEC.

Comment: @Programmer66  Not really, there's no ground screws on the fixture and no ground on the outlet... it's old, before grounding. diagram shows no grounding.

Comment: @Jack - this is off subject to the original question.  In your example, there is no conflict, the fixture has a two wire plug and the outlet is two wire without ground,   The ans above provided example of a new house, which would have the ground.  All examples and comments so far are not directly related to a "Prohibited" instructions.

Comment: @Programmer66  My bad, two prong outlet built into the fixture, not a plug, fixture is hard wired....  if you follow direction, you've installed an outlet that isn't GFCI protected... code forbids that now.

Comment: Jack - others, let's <a href="https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112637/nec-vs-manufactures-instructions"> Continue Discussion in Chat here </a>

Comment: @JACK, I'm still not sure that's an actual conflict -- surely the instructions wouldn't say not to put it on a GFCI breaker (since they didn't exist back then), and that's an acceptable way to meet NEC's GFCI requirements.  I don't think the lack of ground is an issue if it's two-prong either, since devices that need ground simply couldn't be used there.  I have UL listed string lights I bought this year that have a two-prong outlet on the end for daisy-chaining, so they're at least not completely forbidden.

Comment: @NateS.  I guess I'm looking at it since the directions were followed it's not GFCI protected, the conflict  is the code now saying it has to be GFCI protected...  Yes, it's easily solved  but could you argue following the directions...  (note:  I would just put in a GFCI at the panel)